# WebStorm 2017.1: TypeScript: import can be shortened inspection issue

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Inspection is raising this issue... according to this [WebStorm blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/09/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-4830-stylelint-usages-for-default-exports-and-more/), I tried to update it but it's raising the same issue for these imports:

**server.ts**

```
....
// models
import { IModel } from './models/model'; //import IModel
import { IUserModel } from './models/user'; //import IUserModel
```

**models/model.ts**

```
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { IUserModel } from "./user";
export interface IModel {
  user: Model<IUserModel>;
}
```

**models/user.ts**

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { IUser } from "../interfaces/user";
export interface IUserModel extends IUser, Document {
  //custom methods for user model would be defined here
}
```

details for update are given [in this post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23306)

```
dir/toExport.ts
    export class Foo {}
dir/index.ts
    export {Foo} from './toExport'
client.ts
    import {Foo} from './dir/toExport' //inspection warining

**after fix**
client.ts
    import {Foo} from './dir'
```

but it does not work as it should do ...

**UPDATE**

WebStorm Code Style preferences for TypeScript

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there are a lot of people which don't want to import directories with `index.ts` by default (it was the default behaviour several EAPs but we had to disable it).

You can enable this behaviour in

> "File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports" -> "Use
>   directory import"

Comment: Thanks for feedback... I did it (Webstorm 2017-1) but the warning I. still there ...  I updated my question with pref snapshot

Comment: @erwin you don't need 'use path relative to tsconfig.json' setting

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand this- and I don't even understand what the inspection warning means... how can it be shortened...? No it can't- not as far as I can see. And nope, changing that setting doesn't make phpStorm shut up about it either :/

Comment: I can confirm the warning still does not go away on WebStorm 2023.1, no matter whether "Use directory import" is checked or not. I want to always use relative paths while in the same module, even if they are longer than the aliased paths we use for cross-module imports.